# website to install applications directly to the system

Tags: web, system

is it possible to have websites installing applications (games and softwares) directly onto the system? the webpage may copy the required installation files from the server onto the specified destination on the system and also be give access to the systems registry so as to modify it. there'll be no need to download the setup files for applications in that way. they can even be given access to modify the file system of hardware devices.

Comment: I believe it is possible

Comment: if it is possible, then i would definitely like to work upon it. don't think that's possible under web 2.0, will have to develop something else.

Comment: If you use windows, it will be easy by Microsoft.NET like asp.net. The code can access the system. Like copy file, modify registry and so on.

Comment: It's good to know that's possible under the .net framework. can you help me with some tutorials on this?

Comment: As a starter article, you can try [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/Santhi.M/RegistryAccess11262005020323AM/RegistryAccess.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I've seen this done as you describe is through an Adobe Air application. Of course, the user will have to download and install Adobe Air, but they only have to do this once for the lifetime of their computer.

You can then present the user a button with a special command to tell Adobe Air to install your application

Here's an example of one such installer: http://www.earthbrowser.com/install/